# What consulate do I have to go to if my contract is from a different country than where I will be working?

Tags: visas, germany, work, denmark

Hi all I received a work contract today from a company that is primarily in Germany, however they are officially registered in Denmark.

I am an American citizen and have an appointment at the German consulate next week, however after looking through my contract, I see that there are mentions of it being a Danish company.

Would I have to go to the Danish consulate instead?

I will only be living/working in Germany.

Comment: Surely Denmark cannot provide you with a visa to work in Germany? That principle would open up all sorts of possibilities. Suppose it is an American company with offices in Germany. Would you expect the US to provide you with a visa to work in Germany?

Comment: Also, if you will be working in Germany, they must also be registered there, so they can levy all relevant taxes, and social security contributions.

Comment: @joseph Schafer What advice has your new employer given?

Comment: I believe that you guys are right, I will continue to go to the German consulate.

Comment: @Traveller they are a start-up and I am their first Non-EU employee so we're figuring this out together.